# mocked method won't return object

Tags: .net, unit-testing, moq

im using .net mvc3 to build simple app. I wrote couple of test cases and i have problem with one of them. Im using Moq to mock my domain service, i have this two methods:

```
List<Customer> customersRepo =
{
  new Customer{
   Id = 0,
   Name = "Jojo"
  },
  new Customer{
   Id = 1,
   Name = "John"
  }
}

mock.Setup(m => m.GetByName(IsAny<string>())).Returns<string>(
 n =>
 customersRepo.Where(c => c.Name == n)
);

mock.Setup(m => m.GetById(IsAny<int>())).Returns<int>(
  n=>
  customersRepo.Where(c => c.Id == n)
);
```

The problem is that when i use the mock object's method to fetch customer by name i get the one i asked for, but when i try to fetch by id i always get null object from the mock object.. i tried both with id 0 and 1.. What can be the problem?

Thanks

Comment: I can't believe that either of those setups works as expected. Both setups return an `IEnumerable<Customer>`, but one says it returns a `string` and the other says it returns an `int`. Both of which are not `IEnumerable<Customer>`.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should return first or default customer:

```
mock.Setup(m => m.GetById(IsAny<int>())).Returns<int>(
  id =>
  customersRepo.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Id == id)
);
```

Also keep in mind, that you don't need to re-implement your repository logic in mocks (that is weird and very fragile). It is mock. You can mock any result you want without any logic:

```
mock.Setup(m => m.GetById(42)).Returns<int>(new Customer { Id = 42 });
```

Use mocks to verify interaction - i.e. that clients of your repository called expected method with expected parameters.

---

If you want to test business logic of some service, then service is a system under test (SUT) and you should not mock it. But if your service has both business logic and data access logic, then it does too many things. Extract data access logic to some repository class, which will implement interface:

```
public interface ICustomerRepository
{
    Customer GetById(int id);
    // other methods related to customr data access
}
```

Then make your service depend on this interface (dependency inversion):

```
public class YourService
{
   private readonly ICustomerRepository _repository;
   // dependency injection
   public YourService(ICustomerRepository repository)
   {
       _repository = repository;
   }

   public void ExecuteSomeBusinessLogic()
   {
       // your code will go here
   }
}
```

Then write tests for service. Thus service requires dependency (customer repository) you should mock this dependency. And verify that service interacts with dependency as you expect. E.g. in your ExecuteSomeBusinessLogic test we should check that service will ask for customer with id equal to 42 (yep, weird business logic):

```
[Test]
public void ShouldPerformGoodStuffWhenCustomerFound()
{
    // Arrange
    var mockRepository = new Mock<ICustomerRepository>();
    mockRepository.Setup(r => r.GetById(42)).Returns(new Customer { Id = 42 });
    var service = new YourService(mockRepository.Object);
    // Act
    service.ExecuteSomeBusinessLogic();
    // Assert
    mockRepository.VerifyAll();
    // check other stuff
}
```

If you will write test for case when custom was not found in database, just setup different returns:

```
mockRepository.Setup(r => r.GetById(42)).Returns(null);
```

Comment: I already tried with FirstOrDefault() at the end of the linq, also this is not my repository logic here.. i just simulate data storage as a list and have few records in it.. then i mock my customer service in order to make the unit tests. I will however change the way this is done, i will add new user (preparation for the test) then ill try to get it with the method)

Comment: mock.Setup(m => m.GetCustomerById(It.IsAny<int>())).Returns<int>(
    id => customersRepo.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Id == id)
   );

Comment: What do you mean Returns<Customer>, i read on the internet that the Generic type in returns is actually the type of parameter i want to receive inside the mocked method so i can act based upon that parameter, that is the int is the actual id that i send when i call the GetById method on the mocked object..

Comment: @stefo0O0o sorry, I missed syntax a bit. What is signature of `GetCustomerById` method?

Comment: i haven't been doing much unit-testing and mocking (still learning) but what's the point to do unit testing if i am mocking the whole service.. shouldn't i mock just the repository and use my already coded (or to be implemented) service in order for my test to make sure that my service is robust and security-tight?

Comment: Since, obviously the data source is not important to me, but whether the service is coded properly before anything goes in the db as new record or update..

Comment: @stefo0O0o if you are testing some class, which uses service, then you should mock whole service. Otherwise your test can pass or fail due to errors in service implementation. Errors in service implementation should not affect tests of other classes - only tests of service should fail

Comment: i want to test my service for business logic correctness. Say i have CustomerService which uses entity framework to connect to an underlying db. I want to test whether my methods sanitize input and handle unexpected situations correctly. So, what should be the mock here.. i can't clearly mock the methods of the service, i feel like i need to use the methods already implemented in my service implementation, and just mock the underlying data source. I mean, mock the db with list of customer objects instead. Im a bit confused, i get me self one good book :)

Comment: @stefo0O0o I've added sample of test-driven approach and correct mocks usage. And about book - take a look on [Growing Object-Oriented Software, Guided by Tests](http://www.amazon.com/Growing-Object-Oriented-Software-Guided-Tests/dp/0321503627). It's very good.

Answer (score 0):

I actually just changed a bit my infrastructure.. now my service get's DataSource interface object in the constructor.. which is independent data source and it relies on it to get customer objects, ofc. after it checks for the business rules and does any needed sanitation of the user input.. So now, i will just mock my data source (a list with customer objects) in the unit test and feed an instance of my service with this mocked repo of customer objects.. this way i can test my already coded service business logic for correctness. Previously i had coupled the service with specific data storage (that is db using EF DbContext) and it was a bit hard to use the service in the unit test since it was already coupled with the db, but i didn't wanted to alter and revert back the db state just to perform my unit-tests, so i wanted to simulate the data storage with simple list of customer objects.. Thanks for your efforts, helped me there :)